# How to manually curry a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, functional-programming, currying

I encountered a js lib which provided the external ts types. Assuming it's

```
interface ComplicatedFunction {
    (n: number, p: any): string,
    (s: string, p: any): number,
    (b: boolean, p: any): number,
}

declare const fn: ComplicatedFunction
```

I want to curry it:

```
import fn from 'fn'
const curriedFn = (p1: ?) =>
    (p2: any) =>
        fn(p1, p2)
```

The question is what is how to fill the p1's type? (all strict checks on)

I tried using generic to fix the types:

```
const curry2 = <P1, P2, R>(fn: (n: P1, m: P2) => R) =>
    (n: P1) => (m: P2) => fn(n, m)

const curriedFn = curry2(fn)
```

unfortunately, the `curriedFn` falls into signature `(b: boolean, p: any): number`. The other two function signatures are omitted by this way.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function has some parameters that decide the result type, you will need to use a similar type for the curried function. Unfortunately, type inference will not help you here, you will need to specify the type manually, and use some extra type assertions when calling the original function:

```
const curriedFn : {
    (n: number): (p: any) => string,
    (s: string): (p: any) => number,
    (b: boolean): (p: any) => number,
} = (p1: number | string | boolean) => (p2: any) => <any>fn(<any>p1, p2)
```

Comment: Actually, the lib is [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/typings/styled-components.d.ts). I want to curry `styled` function. With your solution, I have to export a lot of interfaces used in ThemedBaseStyledInterface.

Comment: The types file: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/typings/styled-components.d.ts#L53:18

Comment: I just tried with that specific function, and it contains a type that is  not exported (`WithOptionalTheme`) so that makes it more difficult to reexport like this. But if it weren't for that, the solution would work, you don't need to reexport all the other types.

Comment: I am not sure of what exactly you are trying to accomplish, for this particular case, but the approach you would have to use should be similar

Comment: The specific goal usage is: 'const styleWith = (template: TemplateStringsArray, ...args: any[]) => (Comp: ?) => styled(Comp)(template, ...args)'

Comment: The declaration is the right solution. You could implement it without types at all: `= (p1: any) => (p2: any) => fn(p1, p2) as any`, more easy to read IMO.

Comment: @Paleo `any` cause the curriefFn losing safe type.